# CSS transition inner div elements on div hover

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to change the opacity of some text in my div when hover over happens :

currently my transition looks like this, and it just moved the box up a bit:

```
.bg-onebyone {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background: #17B6A4 none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
}

.bg-onebyone:hover {
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

In my div.bg-onebyone I have another div holding some text like this

```
.bg-onebyone .widget-stats .stats-icon {
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And what I want to do is just when the main div is hovered over I want to also increased the above opacity in the transition. How can I do this ?

```
<a href="/url">
    <div class="widget widget-stats bg-onebyone">
        <div class="stats-icon stats-icon-lg">
            <i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="stats-desc">Creating Grouped Unmatched Aliases</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Please post some  HTML.

Comment: Posted the entire div above, basically I want to create a transition when the div is hovered over to increase opacity on "stats-icon"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `:hover` pseudo-class on parent and then select the child element.

```
.bg-onebyone:hover .stats-icon {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Also `.bg-onebyone .widget-stats .stats-icon` is incorrect for your HTML markup since it targets `.stats-icon` as a grand-child of `.bg-onebyone` which does not exist.

**Output:**

```css
.bg-onebyone {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #17B6A4 none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
}
.bg-onebyone:hover {
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.bg-onebyone .stats-icon {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.bg-onebyone:hover .stats-icon {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget widget-stats bg-onebyone">
  <div class="stats-icon stats-icon-lg">Test text for opacity
    <i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="stats-desc">Creating Grouped Unmatched Aliases</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem :) Please check the CSS selectors page: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048 The CSS selector you were currently using for .stats-icon was not right.

Answer (score 0):

Via JavaScript, use jQuery [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), like this:

```
$( "mainDiv" ).hover(
      function() {
          $("whereToChangeTheOpacity").css( "opacity", "0.5" );
      },
      function() {
          $("whereToChangeTheOpacity").css( "opacity", "0" );      
      }
);
```